# removing a particular line from a file in python.

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to remove the First line from the output file (arista_dataset2), i serached and have seen lot of suggestion but most of the solution didn'y worked for me and i came around with the solution `res_data = res_Out.split("\n",1)[1];`
 which works. Though, i'm looking for an elegant solution if here can be one.

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, division, print_function
import netmiko
import json

def arista_Connect():
    filename = "arista_dataset2"
    connection = netmiko.ConnectHandler(ip='192.1.1.1', device_type='arista_eos', username='netuser', password='secrete')
    #print(connection.send_command('show ip arp', max_loops=1000, delay_factor=20))
    res_Out = connection.send_command('show ip arp',delay_factor=20)
    #res_data = res_Out[1:]
    res_data = res_Out.split("\n",1)[1];
    #print(res_Out)
    #return res_Out
    filedata = open(filename, mode='w+', encoding='utf-8')
    # while writing the entire dataset to a outfile Just eleminate the first line from it
    filedata.write(res_data)
    filedata.close
    connection.disconnect()

#arista_Connect()
if __name__=='__main__':
    arista_Connect()
```

The data into `arista_dataset2` File is as follows:
I'm Just removing the line starting with `^Address`.

```
Address         Age (min)  Hardware Addr   Interface
127.1.0.2               0  0010.gh587.b001  Internal1/1
192.102.1.20            0  2c21.099a.9c01  Management1/1
192.102.1.23            0  c4f5.6061.b8dd  Management1/1
192.102.1.25            0  c4f5.1b49.66a9  Management1/1
192.102.1.46            0  001c.7c03.1470  Management1/1
```

Comment: Looks like a perfectly fine solution to me.

Comment: @glibdud, thx for your comment on this.